# Javascript event for iframe finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm looking for a way to detect and call a function when a hidden iframe finishes downloading a file (or starts downloading the file).

Basically, I have this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("prodFrame");
iframe.src = "url to download file";
$("#prodFrame").load(function(){
    enableDownloadFunction();
});
```

Which doesn't work.  I've also tried `iframe.onload` and get no results either.  With either of these attempts, the file downloads fine but `enableDownloadFunction();` never fires.  The url that loads in the hidden iframe takes about 2 or 3 minutes to do its thing and get the file ready for download.  The actually downloading of the file will only take a second or two.  So, I just want something to happen either when the file begins downloading or has completed downloading - either will work.

Also, I have no access to the server side of things - only client side.

Comment: AFAIK you can't track _file_ download in any way. You can only track _document_ loading, what is never fired in case you open direct link. The best thing you can do is to allow user to use his browser's download manager functionality to download huge files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+iframe+load+event

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I did search and I tried a lot of those solutions.  Did you read my question or just my title?  If you saw a solution in that search that will work for me I'd love to try it.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery ready on iframes document object

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("prodFrame");
    $( iframe.contentDocument ).ready(function() {
        enableDownloadFunction();
    });
});
```

but jep - tested and can't fetch the download event since user is prompted with "chose your location" dialog

Comment: This is firing immediately and not waiting for the file to start downloading or finish downloading.

Comment: Thanks Jaak Kütt.  Unfortunately, the edit you made is still firing immediately.  I'm starting to think this isn't possible as Tommi said.

Comment: atleast the edit made it wait til the iframe tag itself was loaded XD

Comment: I'm actually not prompted.  It just automatically downloads for me.

Comment: if you don't have a download folder specified, you get prompted